# Black screen when using Navigator.push() in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout

I'm trying to use Navigator.push to navigate to a new page in Flutter. This is what I've got so far:

```
GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print('Test');
//              Navigator.push(context,
//                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ResultsPage()));
            },
            child: Container(
              color: Color(0xFFff474b),
              child: Center(
                child: Text('CALCULATE', style: kButtonText),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 80.0,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
            ),
          ),
```

The code that I want to implement is commented out, as I've been testing the onTap with a print statement.

Interestingly, the print statement runs but for some reason, I can't get the Navigator.push to work. It only navigates to a black screen.

For context, this is the Results page - just a simple scaffold with an App Bar. But the App Bar doesn't show up on the next page:

```
class ResultsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Calculated Distance'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error may be caused due to two or more Floating Action buttons present in a scaffold. By default Floating Action button has a Hero property active. Make it deactivate by heroTag: null,.

For eg,

```
FloatingActionButton(
                    heroTag: null,
                    child: Icon(),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahh it turns out that the issues is that I have two FloatingActionButtons on the page, and so it messes with the Navigator route.

This Medium article I found is a nice guide for the solution: https://medium.com/@kaendagger/test-cef30fcb5c54

Answer (score 0):

add ResultsPage() to your routes add this to you MaterialApp(

```
MaterialApp( 
  initialRoute: '/',
              routes: {
                '/': (_) => HOME(),
                '/home': (_) => ResultsPage(),
              }, )
```